# ExtendedSplashScreen Prism StoreApps Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, prism

I need make load data and show ExtendedSplashScreen.

If i use like in this [example](https://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Converged/Quickstarts/ExtendedSplashScreenQuickstart/ExtendedSplashScreen/ExtendedSplashScreen.xaml.cs)

App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ExtendedSplashScreenFactory = (splashscreen) => new ExtendedSplashScreen(splashscreen);
}
```

ExtendedSplashScreen.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class ExtendedSplashScreen : Page
{
    private readonly SplashScreen _splashScreen;

    public ExtendedSplashScreen(SplashScreen splashScreen)
    {
        _splashScreen = splashScreen;

        InitializeComponent();

        SizeChanged += ExtendedSplashScreen_SizeChanged;

        splashImage.ImageOpened += splashImage_ImageOpened;
    }

    void splashImage_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
}
```

i have exception `Invalid Pointer`
[image]
How fix or workaround it?

Comment: First you are using the `Prism.Mvvm` package which hasn't been updated since 2014. Second I might suggest that you use the [Prism.{DI Container of your choice}.Forms](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/) package. For one you'll be using a maintained package, for two it'll allow you to update your solution for iOS, Android, and UWP. I realize that doesn't directly answer your question but I believe you will find a better solution to your problem that way.

Comment: Unfortunately I need write legacy for wp8.1. It's part of my work)

Comment: WP8.1 should still be supported by XF and Prism.Forms is all PCL so anything XF will support Prism.Forms will.